# Get data from rest service using D3

Tags: javascript, json, rest, d3.js

I have a working web service at http://localhost/RestService/GetTransactionByStatus/1. When I run that URL on my browser I'm getting the correct JSON-formatted response:

```
{
    "transactionConcil"      : "TRANSACTIONS OK",
    "numTransactionConcil"   : 0,
    "transactionNoConcil"    : "TRANSACTIONS NOT OK",
    "numTransactionNoConcil" : 0
}
```

How can I manage this REST service in order to present the correct data in my browser using a web service? The data is going to be managed dynamically so the information that is going to be displayed depends on the ID (last param in the URL).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Look at the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#json). Here is an example:

```
d3.json('http://localhost/RestService/GetTransactionByStatus/' + id, function(data) {
    console.log(data.transactionConcil);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

As of d3 v5, this has become

```
    d3.json('http://localhost/RestService/GetTransactionByStatus/' + id)
      .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data.transactionConcil);
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

Update 2019:

For any host - `localhost` or some `server`, you can directly get data by just mentioning `rest api path`, so that your code can be used on any `server`

```
d3.json("/RestService/GetTransactionByStatus/" + id, function(error, data) {
            console.log(data);
});
```