# Initialize data from json variable d3js (javascript)

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

to create a dynamic graphic, i get a json variable from a REST server. I found a way to initialize my graphic from this variable, but i have to apply a function on each data inside before.

Here is a part of my current code :

```
d3.json("test.json", function(data) {
  var parse = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H").parse;

  types = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.type; })
      .entries(stocks = data);

  types.forEach(function(s) {
    s.values.forEach(function(d) { d.jour = parse(d.jour); d.count = +d.count; });
    s.maxCount = d3.max(s.values, function(d) { return d.count; });
    s.sumCount = d3.sum(s.values, function(d) { return d.count; });
  });
  var g = svg.selectAll("g")
      .data(types)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "type");

  setTimeout(lines, duration);
});
```

As you can see , my code use a json file, but it's just for some tests. I can't use this method because my data come from a REST server. Do you have any idea to replace utilisation of the json file to a variable containing the json.

Here, is an example of content from my json :

```
[
{"type":"CAD","jour":"2016-03-29 00","count":28697},
{"type":"CAD","jour":"2016-03-29 01","count":29156},
{"type":"CAD","jour":"2016-03-29 02","count":29799},
{"type":"CAD","jour":"2016-03-29 03","count":30095},
{"type":"CAD","jour":"2016-03-29 04","count":28430},
{"type":"CAD","jour":"2016-03-29 05","count":29124},
{"type":"CAD","jour":"2016-03-29 06","count":28073},
{"type":"CAD","jour":"2016-03-29 07","count":29398},
{"type":"CAD","jour":"2016-03-29 08","count":28522},
{"type":"CAD","jour":"2016-03-29 09","count":15685},
{"type":"ISM","jour":"2016-03-29 00","count":39170},
{"type":"ISM","jour":"2016-03-29 01","count":39143},
{"type":"ISM","jour":"2016-03-29 02","count":39061},
{"type":"ISM","jour":"2016-03-29 03","count":39066},
{"type":"ISM","jour":"2016-03-29 04","count":38529},
{"type":"ISM","jour":"2016-03-29 05","count":39019},
{"type":"ISM","jour":"2016-03-29 06","count":38354},
{"type":"ISM","jour":"2016-03-29 07","count":38195},
{"type":"ISM","jour":"2016-03-29 08","count":37907},
{"type":"ISM","jour":"2016-03-29 09","count":20015}
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using to get the data from the server ? `XMLHttpRequest` or a library like `jQuery` ? You just have to make the call to the server to get the data and inside the success of this request, you initialize the graphic.

Comment: I use jQuery to have my data.  with $.getJSON .... i update my code and i give you a feedback just after (if it works or not). Thanks

Comment: It does'nt works. I tried to put directly my url where i get my data  in the d3.json too but i have the same result. An other solution could be to create a json file from the data in javascript but it's certainly impossible in js (for security reasons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make your server call and initialize the D3 graphic when you received the data from it. Just put your code in the success callback:

```
$.getJSON('/getGraphicData', function(data) {
  var parse = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H").parse;

  types = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {
      return d.type;
    })
    .entries(stocks = data);

  types.forEach(function(s) {
    s.values.forEach(function(d) {
      d.jour = parse(d.jour);
      d.count = +d.count;
    });
    s.maxCount = d3.max(s.values, function(d) {
      return d.count;
    });
    s.sumCount = d3.sum(s.values, function(d) {
      return d.count;
    });
  });
  var g = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(types)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "type");

  setTimeout(lines, duration);
});
```

### EDIT

As @FlorianBury mentioned in the comments, you can also do it like:

```
d3.json('/getGraphicData', function(data) { ... });
```

Comment: @FlorianBury How is this different from your approach using `d3.json()`? If this does works, so does your approach.

Comment: @altocumulus I never tried because in the doc(https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Requests.md#convenience-methods) you can read `d3.json` "Creates a request for the JSON file at the specified url with the mime type "application/json".". But looks like you are right : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236660/get-data-from-rest-service-using-d3

Comment: @altocumulus I think when i put directly my url in my d3.json, it load the complete file and not just the json content. With the documentation in the d3 api, i understood that the function d3.json ca only read data from file and not from variable but maybe i'm wrong. The only thing i'm sure, it's this method works in my case.

Comment: @FlorianBury `d3.json()` and `$.getJSON()` are basically equivalent. They will load the same thing from the same file with differences, if any, being subtle. If this works, however, good for you! The downside is, that you are mixing libraries.

Comment: @FlorianBury Just out of sheer curiosity: please, give it a try with the first line changed to exactly this: `d3.json('/getGraphicData', function(error, data) {`.

Comment: I tried and it's work. When i put an incorrect path to my json, i can display the error correctly. Thanks for the idea, i'll can improve my code with this variable (particullary for debug).